# How to use core-scroll-header-panel with core-drawer-panel

Tags: polymer

I'm wanting to create a layout kinda like google inbox. Specifically:

- A banner that can scroll away (thanks core-scroll-header-panel)
- A long list as the main content (thanks core-list)
- A menu button top left that reveals a core-navigation-panel (rather than a popup)

On the surface that seems like it should be achievable roughly as follows

```
<core-drawer-panel forceNarrow>

  <core-header-panel drawer>
    <core-toolbar></core-toolbar>
    <core-menu>...</core-menu>
  </core-header-panel>

  <core-scroll-header-panel main>
    <core-toolbar></core-toolbar>
    <core-list>....</core-list>
  </core-scroll-header-panel>

</core-drawer-panel>
```

However, my attempts at this have failed (http://jsbin.com/womovo), as the menu for the drawer panel is missing.

Is this layout possible at the moment, either using the above components or others (not sure if core-scaffold helps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the menu is there you can click the edge of the page a pull it out. or run

```
document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel();
```

in console to show it.

edit: i feel like http://jsbin.com/soqopuyiqi is what you are looking for.

Comment: Fwiw, as of 0.5 you can add `core-drawer-toggle` attribute to any clickable element and it will toggle the drawer automatically (so you don't have to hook it the event manually). http://jsbin.com/rucife/2/edit?html,output

Comment: great tip. polymer keeps getting better and better.